# How to use & modifier on a parameter in a C++Function call

Tags: c++, class, constructor, operators

I've been given a task for my cpp homework, the task is long and has many more functions that this, but I am stuck at the beggining. What I am trying to do here is just write out the point that is given on the screen.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
    double x, y;
    Point(){
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
    };
    Point(double x,double y){
        this -> x = x;
        this -> y = y;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "(x,y) = ("<< x <<","<< y <<")"<<endl;
    }
};

class Triangle {
public:
    Point A;
    Triangle(const Point& p1){
        A.x = p1.x; 
        A.y = p1.y;
    }

    void print1(){
        cout << "A(x,y) = ("<< A.x <<","<< A.y <<")"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Triangle A{1.0,2.0};
    A.print1();
    return 0;
}
```

What my thinking here is, I have a class named Point and it is made of two variables x and y, class Triangle in the task has 3 points, but I am using just one for simplicity, it has a point that is from class Point (so it should have x and y coordinates) and a constructor that has a point from class Point also. I was thinking just to link their x and y coordinates and to print them out. But it doesn't work like that, can you help me. I have more code from the task if you need, and code from our lessons. Thank you.

Comment: My biggest problem is the Triangle constructor and not knowing what to put inside { } brackets. I know how to do it with regular variables, but with "const Point&" which is given in the task so we need to use it, I don't know how to.

Comment: `Triangle A({1.0, 2.0});` would work (at least in C++17).  Alternatively, `Triangle A(Point(1.0,2.0));`.

Comment: That was quick. It works! Thank you, been struggling for the past hour or so haha.

Comment: It succesfully compiles the program, but the print seems to not print out anything.

Comment: Something else going on. @Eljay 's suggestion is correct. I'm unable to reproduce any no-print problems.

Comment: Maybe I'm in the wrong here, I compile it using command block, should it even print out A(x,y) = (1.0,2.0), seen as i use print1 and it is defined as so in class Triangle

Comment: It will probably print out *A(x,y) = (1,2)* because the default behaviour of `<<` with floating point numbers is to not display unnecessary digits.

Comment: C++ does have an `&` operator (bitwise AND) but you're not using it anywhere.  The `&` modifier on a type makes a reference type... and is not an operator.  Please fix your title

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the name of that so I just googled and this is the first thing that pooped up, what should i change it to, just replace operator with modifier?

Answer (score 1):

`Triangle(const Point& p1)` accepts a `const` [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) to a `Point`. A reference is an alias to an existing variable. In this case rather than copying in a `Point`, the `Triangle` constructor receives the `Point` itself. The `const` is important because it is a promise that the `Point` will not be modified inside by `Triangle`'s constructor. This allows you to pass in a reference to a temporary `Point` that otherwise would not be around long enough for modification to be meaningful and is rejected by the compiler to prevent possible errors.

```
Triangle A{1.0,2.0};
```

will attempt to make `Triangle` from two floating point values. `Triangle` needs a reference to a `Point`, so you must make that `Point` first.

```
Triangle A{ {1.0,2.0} };
          ^ ^ 
          | Construct a temporary Point from 2 floating point numbers
          Triangle constructor arguments: one Point
```

Unrelated improvement: Use the [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
Triangle(const Point& p1): A{p1}{
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, that clears it up, good explanation, thank you very much.